# Не проходит push на GitHub

Tags: git, git-push

Когда хочу запушить на GitHub, возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас авторизация по ключам. Должен быть приватный ключ. Когда раньше всё удавалось, авторизация тоже по ключам была, или по паролю? Это выставляется в веб-интерфейсе на гитхабе.

Comment: после команды пуш я вводил логин и пароль)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно осуществлять доступ в репозиторий через ssh, а можно через https. Вы добавили удаленный репозиторий как ssh-репозиторий. Логин/пароль используется при доступе по https.  [Вот тут](http://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use) описано подробно различие. Для авторизации по ssh нужны ключи, а по https только логин/пароль.
В вашем случае нужно изменить адрес origin репозитория.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```